# mod_rewrite NE flag - When is it helpful to encode special chars in the URL?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, url-encoding

I've been looking at the `[NE]` (noescape) flag in mod_rewrite. After some thought I couldn't figure out a situation when I would *NOT* want to use the flag. Meaning, it seems most helpful to keep the flag enabled in almost every `RewriteRule`. Not invoking this flag has caused me problems in a few circumstances.

Most of the rules that I deal with are HTTP redirects (`[R]`), rather than passing through.

Would someone shed some light as to **when it is helpful to have mod_rewrite encode the URL?**

Is it generally good practice to enable this flag, or use the default behavior of allowing mod_rewrite escape these special characters? Why?

Comment: Great question, I'm surprised you got no answers yet. And I'm even more surprised that dozens of answers on SO about www to non-www redirects (and vice-versa) do not add the `[NE]` in the `RewriteRule`. You saved my day, I couldn't understand why my url was encoded twice during mod_rewrite redirections. +1

Answer (score 4):

If you look at the [source code for mod_rewrite](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/mappers/mod_rewrite.c?revision=1452128&view=markup#l4553), you'll notice that it sets a `proxy-nocanon` flag if `noescape` is enabled.

In the [revision where that line was first added](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpd/httpd/trunk/modules/mappers/mod_rewrite.c?revision=670061&view=markup#l4463), it also included this comment:

> make sure that mod_proxy_http doesn't canonicalize the URI, and preserve any (possibly qsappend'd) query string in the filename for mod_proxy_http:proxy_http_canon()

Following on from that, if you read the [mod_proxy documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_proxy.html), you'll see the following mention of `nocanon`:

> Normally, mod_proxy will canonicalise ProxyPassed URLs. But this may be incompatible with some backends, particularly those that make use of PATH_INFO. The optional nocanon keyword suppresses this, and passes the URL path "raw" to the backend. Note that may affect the security of your backend, as it removes the normal limited protection against URL-based attacks provided by the proxy.

I'm may be mistaken, but that implies to me that the use of `nocanon` in mod_proxy (and by extension `noescape` in mod_rewrite) has potential security ramifications. That would explain why it is disabled by default, even thought it seems like it would be more useful to have it enabled in most cases.

Answer (score 1):

The `[NE]` flag is extremely useful when you are adding the request url as part of - let's say - an authorization signature.

I just had a bug where authorization was working with .htaccess off but not with it on. It turned out the cause was that redirection was url encoding the items that ended up in the php `$_GET` parameter. To solve the bug I changed:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/0-9])$ $1/ [R=301,L]
```

to

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*[^/0-9])$ $1/ [NE,R=301,L]
```

(the authorization signature is composed of many things, one of these is the request url)

Comment: *"Would someone shed some light as to `when it is helpful to have mod_rewrite encode the URL?`"*

Comment: @Servant -I was answering the why part of, "Is it generally good practice to enable this flag, or use the default behavior of allowing mod_rewrite escape these special characters? Why?" w an example. - Basically sharing an experience w the use of this flag.

Comment: upvoted again as i find this piece of information useful

Comment: Those rules are even wrong, they should say R=301,L.