# mod_rewrite RewriteCond - is NC flag necessary for just domain part? And some more

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, case-insensitive

I have seen many times in `htaccess` these type of rules :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http://www.domain.it$ [NC]
```

or

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.domain\.it$ [NC]
```

**Why is the `NC` flag necessary, when checking only the domain part?**

I noticed **browsers always converts uppercases in domain names into lower cases**, so I don't see what the `[NC]` flag is usueful for in this case.

I mean if we check the remaining part of the url I understand the need for `[NC]` flag cause on Unix systems `www.domain.com/index.html` is different file than `www.domain.com/INDEX.HTML` but I don't understand the need of `NC` flag when we check only the domain part in the RewriteRule.

---

Since you took the time to read the above, **let me ask also one minor question** not directly related to `NC` flag, but still related to `RewriteCond`

Both `RewriteCond` shown above work well, I thought only the one with slash before dots would work (`!^www\.domain\.it$`) because **the dot without a slash should mean *'any char'* in regexp whilest the `\.` means the dot char**, but surpraisingly also the other one works well, do you know why?

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Having `[NC]` is definitely not mandatory but it is recommended to have it for matching domains. Modern browsers might be converting domain names to lowercase but what about old browsers and command line utils like `wget`, `curl` etc, so you should not always rely on clients sending you lowercase domain name and keep `[NC]`.

About your 2nd question `.` matches **any character** therefore it is able to match `www.domain.com` but it will also match `www-domain-com` text which you don't want to match. So it is better to have `www\.domain\.com`

Comment: Thanks. I suppose the 2nd one always worked because it's applied to just a domain, so if osmeone enetered www-domain-com would not even reach the domain at all.

Comment: btw do you have an idea on how to answer to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5279470/mod-rewrite-ne-flag-when-is-it-helpful-to-encode-special-chars-in-the-url

Answer (score 11):

`NC = nocase` means regardless of the case of the incoming referrer traffic match with the given pattern.

See [Apache [NC|nocase] flag](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_nc)

Answer (score 3):

I don't know the [NC] for sure, but I suppose that in some unlikely event the the ENV var. could contain upper case chars.

A dot in a regular expression means one character, any character. SO the first condition would also match if the string is http://www_domain-it or http://wwwadomain1it

Comment: You did not explain it very well, but I got the idea after reading your answer, +1 and thanks!