# HTTPS Redirect .htaccess issue with addon domain

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, https

I own multiple domain names under a single main domain as an addon domain.
I also purchased an SSL certificate for the main domain.
To force all non-SSL to SSL, I use the following .htaccess code:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.maindomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

This works fine, but the issue is if I enter `addondomain.info`, it also redirects to `https://www.maindomain.com/addondomain.info/`.

I want only the main domain to do https redirection.
How to do that?

Note : If I enter `www.addondomain.info`, instead of simply `addondomain.info`, it works fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add another condition to it:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?maindomain\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ https://www.maindomain.com/$1 [R,L]
```

Also, you'll want to place this at the very top of your htaccess file so that it gets applied before any other rules.

Comment: It works great ... Thanks mate .. :) ., By the way just for info may i know what's the meaning or purpose of [NC] in 3rd line ?

Comment: [NC] means "no case" or case insensitive. See http://stackoverflow.com/a/5582488 for a longer explanation.

Answer (score 2):

May vary depending on your hosting conditions, however in my experience, The Only logic that managed to force all to https and exclude a subdomain in a shared hosting environment looks like:

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?ADDON_DOMAIN\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [L]`
# This is *essential* in order to ensure no further conditions are applied after navigating to the add-on domain #
`RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off`
# Now that you've defined your exclusion AND made certain its logic is independent from all other URI Requests, Must re-establish this condition once more #
`RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]`